# CAST-256 (CAST6) versions or S-Boxes

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, test-vectors

Are there different versions of CAST-256 - also known as CAST6 - available? Are there different S-Boxes available for CAST-256? If there are different versions or S-Boxes what identifier should I use to indicate them?

I have an issue with [PHP mcrypt version of CAST-256](http://mcrypt.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mcrypt/libmcrypt/modules/algorithms/cast-256.c?content-type=text%2Fplain) (the link goes to the ill maintained mcrypt library underneath) where I cannot generate the same value as the one in the [test vectors for CAST-256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2612#appendix-A). In case anyone wants to try, I'm using the first test vector from the RFC. The Bouncy Castle libraries (v1.51) for Java seem to generate the correct value.

--

Notes:

- the same code on other block ciphers in mcrypt without issue and triple checked the mcrypt input/output values - code available on request;
- "Applied Cryptography 2nd Edition" by Bruce Schneier talks about *configurable S-Boxes* for the original CAST cipher, but I don't see the same indication for CAST-256 other than
  that it should reuse the S-Boxes of CAST-128;
- there is a *set* of 4 S-Boxes required for CAST-256, so the S-Boxes in the code are all part of the same configuration.